# How to get list of all objects of logged in user's here in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I tried getting the list of objects from the current logged users. There something missing in the codes.
I wrote a class-based view as well as function-based views. 
Class-based views give an error like 1 positional argument but two were given. 
And in function-based view it giving only first item instead looping through it.

I want to show the pass investments inventory record of each investor.

Thank you!

views.py (Function-Based Views)

```
def InvestmentListView(request):
    investors = Investment.objects.all(id=request.user.id)
    args = {'investors':investors}
    return render(request, 'investors/myinvest.html', args)
```

This only retrieving an only first item.

views.py (class-Based viewa)

```
class InvestmentListView(ListView):
    model = Investment
    template_name = 'investors/myinvest.html'
    context_object_name = 'total_invested_by_user'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return  Investment.objects.filter(investor=self.request.user.id)
```

This CBV gives an error like 1 positional argument, but 2 were given.

myinvest.html

```
        <div class="container">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <h2>Investor Name: {{ request.user }}</h2>

                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Amount Invested</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Rate Of Interest</th>
                    <th>Return</th>
                    <th>Profit</th>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                  {% for invest in investors %}
                   <th>{{ invest.amount }}</th>
                   <th>{{ invest.timestamp }}</th>
                   <th>{{ invest.rate }}</th>

                   <th>None</th>
                   <th>None</th>
                  {% endfor %}
                 </tr>



                </table>
           {% endif %}
```

Here, models.py

```
    class Investor(models.Model):  
        name = models.CharField(max_length=99) 
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class Investment(models.Model):
        amount = models.FloatField(blank=False)
        rate = models.FloatField(blank=False)
        timestamp = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
        investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.investor)
```

Comment: add error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering the `Investment` id with your user id which is not correct. This should work:

```py
investors = Investment.objects.filter(investor__user=request.user)
```

Comment: A little help more. Its printing all the record in a single line. Every next inventory should print beneath. Probably some changes in template only.

Comment: You need to put ```<tr>``` tags inside the for loop.